# Question about updating state with useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I'm a bit unclear about how React handles updating state with useReducer.

I have these bits of code as below:

```
function userSelectionsReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'editQtt':
            state[action.data.index].quantity = action.data.value;
            return state;
            break;
        case 'editDate':
            return state.map((item, index) =>
                index == action.data.index ?
                { ...item, deliveryDate: action.data.value} :
                item
            );
            break;
    }
}
const [userSelections, dispatchUserSelection] = useReducer(userSelectionsReducer, {});

useEffect(() => {
   console.log(userSelections) //will reach here with 'editDate' but not 'editQtt'
}, [userSelections])

const logState = () => {
   console.log(userSelections) //will log new value of 'state' after dispatching 'editQtt'
}
....
<button onClick={logState}>Log selections</button>
```

As you can see, the first action I write it so that 'state' value will be updated directly, while in the other one I return a new instance of state with updated value. From what I know (not really sure) the 'state' is immutable & can't be changed directly, but as I observed with the first action, the 'state' value is actually changed but will not trigger re-render on component nor call the callback function of useEffect. But when I manually log it with a dedicated button it shows the updated value.
DO you guys have any idea how it really works? Thanks!

Comment: The state is mutable, but by doing so it will cause the component to not re-render

Comment: When checking for updated values, React will compare the current state object reference to the one you return. In the first one `editQtt` you literally return the existing state object, so a reference comparison will show they're the same object and that will be interpreted as no change having occurred. Thus, no re-render. However, since you mutated the state, the actual value will technically have changed, it's just that React doesn't realise this because it doesn't do deep comparisons. This is why you don't directly mutate the state and always return a new object

Comment: Long story short, reducers are functions that take a current state object and an action, and return a *new* state object, i.e. a new object reference, which is the next state to use.